# Can I access and then replace image based on src value?, using jQuery or otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hell CMS to work with and am wondering if i can do the following with jQuery (or just straight up JS)

images are being displayed with no ID's or classes and I'd like to replace images based on their src value

pseudo code would be something like...

find img where src = /img/00789-reg-1.jpg'; 
and replace src value with ='img/much-better-img.jpg';

thanks -

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: To answer your question's title, yes to both.

Answer (score 5):

Each image is a part of array provided by `document.images`. You can loop through images to find the image with the source you need.

```
var index=0;
while(document.images[index]){
    alert(document.images[index].src);
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:

```
jQuery('img[src=/img/00789-reg-1.jpg]').attr('src','img/much-better-img.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use:

```
var images = document.images;
var iLength = images.length;
for (var i=0; i<iLength; i++){
    thisImage = images[i];
    if (thisImage.src == "theOneThatIWantToReplace"){
        thisImage.src = "myNewSrc"
        break;
    }
}
```

At least this doesn't involve hefting JQuery around if you don't need it.

Comment: To need JavaScript is to need jQuery, since it's faster (to type up) and easier to later review (and understand) jQuery = JavaScript on Steroids (only instead of shrinking anything else, it just shrinks your code length :)

Comment: jQuery is in fact Javascript on Twinkies. It's slow(er), Fat(ter), and Lazy people eat it up in massive numbers.

Comment: Without JavaScript there would be no JQuery.

Comment: `s/document.getElementsByTagName('img')/document.images/`, Please use "var i" and cache the length.

Comment: @VoidKing To *need* (not necessarily use) jQuery is to lack knowledge and understanding with JS. Also the code shrinkage is a myth considering you have to INCLUDE around 9k lines of code just so you can remove a few lines from your own code.

Comment: Very good points all around, but I have found that there are some things that are better (or, seemingly, only possible) in jQuery, not simply JavaScript. The twinkie analogy is pretty accurate, except, there seems to be no real reason why I shouldn't eat it up in massive amounts. Also, when I say "shrinks your code", I mean "YOUR" code. I for one, don't care about the small jQuery library. If you can't squeeze 9K into your site, than you need to find a more viable web host to host your site. jQuery is easier to understand, read, and implement, and I think that matters more than a few K.

Comment: I guess it comes down to what environment you expect to have your app running in. If you expect a lot of mobile visitors (especially cell-phones) then this few K, as well as the minor loss of speed in using jQuery, may, in fact matter. If, in Chrome-like style, you decide that the speed of your app is of paramount importance, this may again matter, so I can see all the points made here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to find your images, then do the replace:

```
$("img[src^='/img']").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "new image");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var  replace = {
  "/img/00789-reg-1.jpg": "img/much-better-img.jpg",
  "/img/another.jpg": "img/another-img.jpg"
}

for (var src in replace){
  $("img[src="+src+"]").attr("src", replace[src]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get all images and then check source of it

```
$('img').foreach(function(o){
  if (o.attr('src')=='oldfile')
    o.attr('src', 'newfile');
});
```

This is long, but I don't know other way.

Comment: I believe you meant to use `.each()` http://api.jquery.com/each/ `Array.forEach` is not applicable here. Your answer as it is throws `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foreach' `